# How can I read the output of a command into two columns using Ansible

Tags: ansible

When I run this command:

```
# hammer --csv --no-headers scap-content list | sort -n | awk -F "," '{printf("\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",$1,$2)}'
"1","Red Hat firefox default content"
"2","Red Hat jre default content"
"3","Red Hat rhel6 default content"
"4","Red Hat rhel7 default content"
```

I get two CSV separated columns ID & Name and I want to read these into Ansible. I can read the contents as one online list e.g.

```
- name: SCAP | List scap-content
  shell: |
         hammer --csv --no-headers --username "{{ hammer.username|default('NotSet') }}" --password "{{ hammer.password|default('NotSet') }}" \
         scap-content list | sort -n | \
         awk -F "," '{printf("\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",$1,$2)}'

  register: scap_content
  tags:          scap

- debug: |
         var=scap_content.stdout.split(",")[0]
  tags:          scap

- debug: var=scap_content.stdout.split(",")[1]
  tags:          scap
```

But I want a list with item.id and item.name so I can process the list one row at a time.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why using csv and turn your brain upside down to parse the content when you can spit it out directly as json or yaml? => https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.2/html/hammer_cli_guide/chap-cli_guide-introduction_to_hammer